# Get top unique results, getting odd .. results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, calendar, unique

i'm pretty new to programming and can't seem to figure out my mistake here.

I have a calendar setup, every time a user changes a day I make a new row.  This way all changes are logged (again new, id imagine there is a better way.) each row has some displayed information but its primary differentiated by a month a day and a year. IE 1 31 2013 .

I need to get the most recent unique row for each day of the month. So if I run a query for 1/31/2013, I need to return only the most recently created row WHERE month= '1' AND etc.

I'm using..

```
SELECT t.* FROM(SELECT * FROM calendar a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM calendar b 
WHERE b.day = a.day AND b.lastaltered > a.lastaltered))  t 
WHERE t.month = '12' AND t.year = '2013'
```

From PHP, if that matters.

Now it works fine if a user makes changes slowly. But I found if someone is quick with it like entering multiple days which end up having a very close time stamp ("lastaltered") it doesn't return that row with my current query. I tested this by modifying the time stamp to a later date and it then returned normally. I hope that explains my problem well enough. I'm still not clear as to why altering the time stamp caused the row to return.

Thank you for your time! 
- Jer

Answer (score 0):

Ah ... managing time in a database that doesn't understand what time is (and none of them do).

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), read the first book - it explains the intricacies of time and the difficulties of using one data type (DateTime) to represent different concepts:

- A fixed instant: 10:15am 4 December 2013 UTC
- A recurring instant: 10:15am every day, every Tuesday or the last Monday of a month
- An instant defined from an anchor: 2 hours from now
- A floating interval: 2 hours
- An anchored interval: 2 hours from 10:15am to 12:15pm 4 December 2013 UTC
- An instant that does not exist: 2:30 am Sunday 5 October 2014 Australian Eastern Daylight Time
- An instant that happens twice 1 hour apart: 2:30am Sunday 6 April 2014 Australian Eastern Daylight Time
- ... and you get the idea.

The cleanest way to handle your problem is to have a ValidFrom and ValidTo DateTime field, when the user creates the row the ValidFrom is set to now and the ValidTo is set to NULL and a trigger executes that sets all the old entries with a NULL ValidTo to now. This will give a complete audit trail and you can get the current entry by querying for the one with the NULL ValidTo.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be exactly what i need.  my thought process is to as you said whenever a insert occurs to set all other same "day" (day defined as month/day/year) to "false" using a bit column. only thing I need to figure out is how to have the trigger get the month = x day = y year = z from the insert and occur before the insert. (to set all other fields to false) The before part is easy enough I see there is a before keyword.